# Get AVAudioEngineGraph programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, core-audio

In my app I created an AVAudioEngine and attached AVAudioNodes on it.

- Is it possible to get the attached nodes programmatically?
- Is it possible to get the nodes connected to a given AVAudioNode?

When I log the engine's description I can see all the AVAudioEngineGraph, but I cannot find the way to get this information programmatically, can someone give me a solution?

```
(lldb) po _engine

________ GraphDescription ________
AVAudioEngineGraph 0x7fb04541ac60: initialized = 1, running = 1, number of nodes = 4

 ******** output chain ********

 node 0x600002448c00 {'auou' 'rioc' 'appl'}, 'I'
     inputs = 1
         (bus0, en1) <- (bus0) 0x60000244cd00, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

 node 0x60000244cd00 {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, 'I'
     inputs = 1
         (bus0, en1) <- (bus0) 0x600002473680, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
     outputs = 1
         (bus0, en1) -> (bus0) 0x600002448c00, {'auou' 'rioc' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

 node 0x600002473680 {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, 'I'
     inputs = 1
         (bus0, en1) <- (bus1) 0x600002462580, {'auou' 'rioc' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
     outputs = 1
         (bus0, en1) -> (bus0) 0x60000244cd00, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

 node 0x600002462580 {'auou' 'rioc' 'appl'}, 'I'
     outputs = 2
         (bus0, en0) -> (bus0) 0x0, {}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
         (bus1, en1) -> (bus0) 0x600002473680, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

 ******** input chain ********

 node 0x600002462580 {'auou' 'rioc' 'appl'}, 'I'
     outputs = 2
         (bus0, en0) -> (bus0) 0x0, {}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
         (bus1, en1) -> (bus0) 0x600002473680, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

 node 0x600002473680 {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, 'I'
     inputs = 1
         (bus0, en1) <- (bus1) 0x600002462580, {'auou' 'rioc' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
     outputs = 1
         (bus0, en1) -> (bus0) 0x60000244cd00, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

 node 0x60000244cd00 {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, 'I'
     inputs = 1
         (bus0, en1) <- (bus0) 0x600002473680, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
     outputs = 1
         (bus0, en1) -> (bus0) 0x600002448c00, {'auou' 'rioc' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

 node 0x600002448c00 {'auou' 'rioc' 'appl'}, 'I'
     inputs = 1
         (bus0, en1) <- (bus0) 0x60000244cd00, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
```

---

Comment: Since you yourself made the graph, how can you not know what it is?

Comment: Yes I can find a workaround and save a temporary variable with the nodes I need to initialize once the engine is running. I was looking for a more straightforward way, to manage the complexity of my audioUnits host. It seems to me strange there is not a property / method exposed by AVAudioEngine or AVAudioNode to get the connected objects. After all the log has all the information I need, it would be enough to get the AudioComponentDescription

Comment: If you have a good use case, file an enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: thank you @matt I addressed the problem in a different way. I guess what I needed is possible by using AUGraph instead of AVAudioEngine but it required the complete refactoring of my audio objects, and of course much more pain :)

Comment: I think to trash this question to allow a better search on stackoverflow

Comment: You should answer your own question and give your solution! Perfectly legal on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to manage custom initializations I created audioUnit wrappers for each category (or specific) audioUnits I am going to load. These wrappers are provided by a factory and referenced by a business object of my app.

The wrapper I mainly worked on up to now, is the so called AUMIDISynth

```
componentType = kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice;
componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_MIDISynth;
componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
```

which allows to load and play different patches from a soundBank file at the same time.

The subclass wrapper for AUMIDISynth exposes a method called

```
-(NSError*)loadProgramChange:(uint8_t)programChange channel:(uint8_t)channel;
```

Other objects (SynthPlayers) observe the notifications sent from the AudioEngine start, and respond to this notification by calling the above method to their own audioUnit wrapper implemented as follows

```
-(NSError*)loadProgramChange:(uint8_t)programChange channel:(uint8_t)channel{  
    NSError *error;
    if (!self.audioUnit.engine || !self.audioUnit.engine.isRunning) {
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain code:-1 userInfo:nil];
    }
    uint32_t enabled = 1;
    OSStatus status = AudioUnitSetProperty(
                                           self.audioUnit.audioUnit,
                                           kAUMIDISynthProperty_EnablePreload,
                                           kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                           0,
                                           &enabled,
                                           sizeof(enabled));
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"error %d",status);
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain code:-1 userInfo:nil];
    }
    uint8_t pcCommand = 0xC0 | channel;
    status = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.audioUnit.audioUnit, pcCommand, programChange, 0, 0);
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"error %d",status);
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain code:-1 userInfo:nil];
    }

    enabled = 0;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(
                                  self.audioUnit.audioUnit,
                                  kAUMIDISynthProperty_EnablePreload,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                  0,
                                  &enabled,
                                  sizeof(enabled));
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"error %d",status);
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain code:-1 userInfo:nil];
    }
    return error;
}
```